# Javascript Number Format Display

Tags: javascript, formatting, numeric

See the simple test program below. In the alert, I need to display the variable MaxPrice with two decimals. I've place $Maxprice in the test program, but in reality, $MaxPrice is read from a SQL file and is a numeric field with a numeric value (in this case 2.00). The alert is displaying only "2". How do I get it to display "2.00"?

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function myFunction()
{
PriceEntered=document.forms["form1"]["Price"].value;
MaxPrice=document.forms["form1"]["MaxPrice"].value;
alert("Price Entered=" + PriceEntered + " and maximum= " +  MaxPrice );
}
</script>
</head>

<?php
$MaxPrice=2.00;
?>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="myFunction ()" action="test.php">
<input name="MaxPrice" id="MaxPrice" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $MaxPrice;?>">
<input name="Price" id="Price" type="text" value="3.00">
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value"Submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `alert("Price Entered=" + Number(PriceEntered).toFixed(2) + " and maximum= " +  Number(MaxPrice).toFixed(2));`.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the `echo` is not really echoing 2.00 but instead just 2, so you may want to look into that. Possibly relevant: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

From the JavaScript perspective though, try the [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method, e.g.

```
MaxPrice = parseFloat(MaxPrice).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var num = 2;
alert(num.toFixed(2));
```